# empty path (/) not redirecting to dashboard in angular 17

Tags: angular-routing, angular11, angular-router-guards, angular17

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with angular. Recently I updated angular version from 11 to 17. In 11 when I entered `http://localhost:4200/` it redirects to `http://localhost:4200/app/main/dashboard`. But after updating to 17 it do not redirects to `http://localhost:4200/app/main/dashboard`. It only loads `http://localhost:4200/` and shows a blank page. Even after login it do not redirect to `http://localhost:4200/app/main/dashboard` by default if there is no **redirectUrl**. Though I have defined root routing in RootRouteModule, but these routes are not triggered. Below is the root route declaration for both version 11 and version 17.

**RootRouteModule in Version 11:**

`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { AppUiCustomizationService } from '@shared/common/ui/app-ui-customization.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/main/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/main/welcome-page', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () => import('account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule), //Lazy     load account module
        data: { preload: true }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
```

`

**RootRouteModule in Version 17:**

`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { AppUiCustomizationService } from '@shared/common/ui/app-ui-customization.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/main/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/main/welcome-page', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () => import('account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule), //Lazy     load account module
        data: { preload: true }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {})],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
```

`

I thought the AppRouteGuard was not triggering that's why it was not working. I tried changing the AppRouteGuard. But none of my attempts worked. I don't know what is the issue here after updating angular 17.

Kindly help me fixing this issue...

Comment: where is route if possible share workable example may be share stackblitz

Comment: I am sorry,  sharing workable example in stackblitz is not possible.

Comment: then share some error log or something

Comment: Giving no error. If I manually enter login route then it works. I don't know how to get error logs. What I can share is what I already shared. Can you tell what you exactly need?